# How can i define different scope for attribute on xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

```
<Metamodel>
  <Package Name="serhat">
    <OwnedType>
      <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
    </OwnedType>
  </Package>
  <Package Name="serhat2">
    <OwnedType>
      <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
    </OwnedType>
  </Package>
  <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
</Metamodel>
```

i have name attribute on elements.This name attribute must be unique in Package element
but in Class element name attribute may repeat on another class element like;

```
  <Package Name="serhat">
    <OwnedType>
      <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
    </OwnedType>
  </Package>
  <Package Name="serhat2">
    <OwnedType>
      <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
    </OwnedType>
  </Package>
```

how can i define this attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is not in the attribute, but in a identity constraint. So, a generated XSD would look like this (I assume the Class under Package must somehow repeat):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Metamodel">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Package">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="OwnedType">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element ref="Class" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:unique name="ClassNameUniqueInPackage">
                        <xsd:selector xpath="OwnedType/Class"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@Name"/>
                        </xsd:unique>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element ref="Class"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Class">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

With this assumed model, the following XML will validate:

```
<Metamodel>
    <Package Name="serhat">
        <OwnedType>
            <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
            <Class Name="serhat2"></Class>
        </OwnedType>
    </Package>
    <Package Name="serhat2">
        <OwnedType>
            <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
        </OwnedType>
    </Package>
    <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
</Metamodel>
```

But not this:

```
<Metamodel>
    <Package Name="serhat">
        <OwnedType>
            <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
            <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
        </OwnedType>
    </Package>
    <Package Name="serhat2">
        <OwnedType>
            <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
        </OwnedType>
    </Package>
    <Class Name="serhat"></Class>
</Metamodel>
```

The error would be:

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 5 position 5
There is a duplicate key sequence 'serhat' for the 'ClassNameUniqueInPackage' key or unique identity constraint.
```